# magento price cart rule buy 2 items from same category get 1 free

Tags: magento

I want to give discount to my customer, if they buy 3 items from category 8 (panty) they'll get the third one free.  So if the system detect there is 3 (panties) in the cart the third or cheapest one will be free.  how to setup the condition to achieve the result

Answer (score 1):

It is impossible to do out of the box in Magento. Out of the box, Magento only allows BOGO discounts on the same items. That is, you can set up a rule that discounts the third exact same product in the customer's cart.

To set up a BOGO cart rule for products from the same category, you need a third party extension. One of the extensions that implement this functionality is [Additional Promotions](https://www.mexbs.com/additional-promotions-magento2-extension).

**Disclaimer: I am the CEO of the company that developed this extension.**